# A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that neither is an $F_\sigma$ set nor a $G_\delta$ set

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone give me a simple example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is neither an $F_\sigma$ set nor a $G_\delta$.